# Let $G$ be a group and $|G|=360$. What is the maximum amount of information we can get about the subgroups of $G$ using sylow?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $|G|=360=2^33^25$. Now from Sylow's first theorem, we can concluded that $G$ has at least one subgroups of order $2^3,2^2,2,3^2,5$ for each $p^k$. In my understanding, I can extract exactly these informations from $\textbf{Sylow's first theorem}$

Now we know that, any group of prime order is cyclic. So, the subgroups of order $5,3,2$ are cyclic (means abelian too). Now as any group of order $p^2$ is abelian, so the subgroups of order $4,9$ are abelian.

Now, coming to $\textbf{Sylow's second theorem}$, we get, the group of order $2$ is contained in the group of order $4$ and $\textbf{Sylow-2subgroup}$ of order $4$ is embedded in the subgroup of order $8$. Similarly we can do for the subgroups of order $3$.
Now as per my understanding, from my class Sylow's second theorem also says that any two $\textbf{Syl_p}$ subgroups are conjugate of each other.

Now coming to $\textbf{Sylow's third theorem}$, I am really confused.

It tells that the number $r$ of Sylow-p subgroups of $G$ is equal to $1$ modulo $p$ and divides the other prime products.
That means in my case as $|G|=2^3*3^2*5$ I can tell that the number $r$ of Sylow 3-subgroups of $G$ is $1$ mod $3$ and divides $2^3*5=40$.
So $r$ can be $10$ only. I know my understanding is wrong here. Please help with my doubt.

Comment: There is no Sylow 2-subgroup of order 4. The Sylow 2-subgroups have order 8.

Comment: Is $10$ really the only divisor of $40$ that equals $1\bmod 3$? (In context of Sylow also the trivial divisors $1$ and $40$ are allowed, but maybe you find even more...)